# How to enable and disable onclick images

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I have 50 images. With OnCLick function, I would like to enable the 10 images and disable the remaining 40.

Comment: The Question is not clear , if you want answers ,please explain more

Comment: Please include a sample of your code and expound on what you're looking for.

Comment: You can't enable images, you can only enable and disable input elements. Do you mean you want to hide and show them?

Comment: In additional to clarify the above, please also specify how you're distinguishing between the 10 images you like from the 40 you don't. Should that be done randomly?

Comment: @  Kanishka Panamaldeniya @ Hydrothermal $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
 $(".btn1").hide();
    $change1 = true;
    test5Click();
      });});
   //Javascript code                                                              <img onclick="DoAllThese();" value="Add" src="../images/Luzon/burnham/bambo-panel.png" class="bamboo-panel" width="78" height="54" /> ~~~for example I have 50 of this, but i want only 10 images are enable to click and every time I reload the local page another 10 different images will be enable to click but the remaining 40 still on page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you queation was you have 50 image witn onclick function.i.e.

```
<img id="1" class="clickimage" src="green.png" onclick="clickedItem()">
<img id="2" class="clickimage" src="green.png" onclick="clickedItem()">
<img id="3" class="clickimage" src="green.png" onclick="clickedItem()">
..............................................
<img id="50" class="clickimage" src="green.png" onclick="clickedItem()">
```

You want onclick function for first 10.
If question is this.

answer:

```
//get all images 
var images = $(".clickimage");

//remove attr onclick after 10th items
for(var i=10;i<images.length;i++){
    $(images[i]).attr('onclick','');
}
```

thanks.

i Understand you problem. you have to write proper code in proper place.

Code will be like 
[image]

and out put will in console

[image]

Comment: you get what I mean sir but the code you've given is not working sir. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i followed the codes but we don't have the same output in the console

Comment: did you refer Jquery? then it should work. my case it working.